# Pascal got word expected short string

Tags: graphics, syntax-error, pascal

```
program MouseInput;
Uses WinCrt,WinMouse, Graph;
Var
   GraphicsDriver, GraphicsMode,
   ErrCode : smallint;
   x, y: shortstring;

Begin
x:=GetMouseX;
Y:=GetMouseY;

     Writeln('Initialising Graphics, please wait...');
     GraphicsDriver := Detect;
     InitGraph(GraphicsDriver, GraphicsMode,'');
     GetmouseX();
     GetmouseY();
     OuttextXY(0,0,x);
     readln();
end.
```

It give me the error:
23 / 20 mouse.pas
 Error: Incompatible types: got "WORD" expected "SHORTSTRING"
But i don't know how to change it so it works becase GetmouseX needs to be Word.

Comment: I can't believe you're using 1980-s era Turbo Pascal with DOS graphics!!!!  *Delete* your "GetMouseX" and "getMouseY " functions!!!  Just call the Turbo graphics versions: "`x := GetMouseX;` and `y := GetMouseY;`.  That's *all* you need to do!

Comment: wait, sorry to sound stupid, but do i not need the function bit ?

Comment: i changed the code look above ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GetMouseX and GetMouseY functions don't return a result and where you call them doesn't read the result, I'd have thought you'd get a stack overflow error since they call themselves (or is this a compiler error).

Having just seen paulsm's comment (I can't remember the Turbo Pascal functions) I think your code should be like this:

```
 InitGraph(GraphicsDriver, GraphicsMode,'');
 x := GetmouseX();
 y := GetmouseY();
 OuttextXY(0,0,x);
```

From [Your link](http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/RPMS/myrpms/lazarus/fpc-lazarus-doc/rtl/mouse/getmousex.html):

```
InitGraph(GraphicsDriver, GraphicsMode,'');
InitMouse;
x := GetmouseX;
y := GetmouseY;
```

Comment: 14 / 11 mouse.pas
 Error: Identifier not found GETMOUSEX
15 / 11 mouse.pas
 Error: Identifier not found GETMOUSEY
16 / 20 mouse.pas
 Error: Incompatible types: got "WORD" expected "SHORTSTRING"

Comment: i fixed the word to shortstring

Comment: changed x, y: word; to x, y: shortstring;

Comment: But its just the identifyers

Comment: He is using mymouse which he must have coded himself, i am using WinMouse

Comment: GetMouseX and GetMouseY return shortstrings? Then you shouldn't need the 2nd calls to GetMouseX() and GetMouseY(), since they don't read the result, it's been a while since I did Turbo Pascal!

Comment: the only problem is that GetMouseX and GetMouseY are not declared as variables. But they shouldn't need to be ?

Comment: 12 / 11 mouse.pas
 Error: Identifier not found GETMOUSEX
that is the error

Comment: http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/RPMS/myrpms/lazarus/fpc-lazarus-doc/rtl/mouse/getmousex.html

Comment: Thanks for trying mate, i have got to go now. Cheers for the time.

Comment: I've changed my answer based on your link, but it uses the Mouse unit, not WinMouse.

Answer (score 1):

Change X,Y back to word and change the outtextxy line to

```
      OuttextXY(0,0,inttostr(x));
```

Make sure "sysutils" is in your uses clause